Minimum work done on a mass to take it along a path

A particle of mass 1 kg is taken along the path ABCDE from A to E (see figure). The two "hills" are of heights 50m and 100m and the horizontal distance AE is 20m while the path length is 400m. The coefficient of friction of the surface is 0.1. Take g = 10SI and √3 = 1.73. The minimum work on the mass required to accomplish this is:


The problem appeared in Indian National Physics Olympiad(INPhO) 2009, Part A, Q.No. 19.
Now, to solve the problem what I did is assume the following:

that the minimum work will be done when we haul the mass up and down the hill slowly, that is, no change in kinetic energy, that is, mass is very slowly moved. In other words, external force whose work is required is applied with such magnitude that the net force on mass is zero.

also, the force whose work is to be calculated acts in the direction tangential to the path.


Using the assumptions I've made, I can apply a technique inspired from the following problem:

A body of mass m was slowly hauled
up the hill (fig. 1.29) by a force F which at
each point was directed along a tangent to the trajectory. Find the work performed by this force, if the height of the hill is h, the length of its base is l, and the coefficient of friction is k.

Taken from Irodov - Problems in General Physics
The answer to the above question is, $mg(h + kl)$
Which means, work done by force depends only on the legs of the right triangle seen in the figure.
When $h = 0$, then the path may be like the one shown in the first figure, the work done becomes: $mg(kl)$ ... (Note that, $h=0$ implies same horizontal level, between the starting and ending points)
However, the answer to the first problem is zero and we don't obtain zero with the above analysis.
What's wrong here. Are my assumptions wrong. Or is the mapping of the two problems wrong(mapping however needs both assumptions to be true, except the minimum work done condition). Or anything else.
Any help is appreciated.

Didn’t you ask this question before?

I'm not sure I am in agreement with the "answer" to the first question being zero.  Also it's not clear if "minimum work on the mass" means the minimum total work done or the minimum energy that needs to be added just to get it to point D.

@BobD yes sir, but this time I got an upvote

@MarianoG It is the minimum work done by a force an external agent applies, therefore, it is the change in total energy: ΔU+ΔK=W(ext.). That's what I believe it should be.

@MarianoG >I'm not sure I am in agreement with the "answer" to the first question being zero. Using the analysis of 2nd question the answer comes out to be 20 Joule. However, the answer key I have says it's 0 Joule

I agree, the question needs to be more clear. It seems like there are unspoken assumptions about what is counting as work on the downhill sections. If the answer is $0$, it sounds like they are assuming you ""accumulate" an opposite sign of work on the downhill sections. The problem is that you always need to specify which force(s) you are talking about when asking about work being done. Is the problem asking about a single applied force, net force? What?

Maybe this is a vocabulary test where "minimum work on the mass required" has a special meaning.  But friction is not conservative.  It's true that you have the same mechanical PE and KE at point E as point A.  But friction has been heating the mass and/or the ground for the entire trip.  You do extra work on the way up the hills but then you don't get it all back on the way down. I don't see how the answer could be zero under any assumptions.

@MarianoG "I don't see how the answer could be zero under any assumptions." BobD's answer has a possible explanation as "work on the mass" could just mean the total work, in which case the least amount you can have is when $\Delta K=0$. Many physics problems fall into this awful trap of "work done on the object" or the one I hate the most "work done against [insert force here]". All you need to specify work is a force and a path, and that is all that should be mentioned to be unambiguous.

@BioPhysicist "I agree, the question needs to...": the condition is that the work must be minimum, and so for that the force may be of different magnitudes at different sections of the path and in different directions. I assumed that, that force is just of the magnitude of the friction + gravity uphill so that we get the least force and therefore least work is done. Downhill, external force should be just equal to friction minus gravity. To equate the external force like done, is merely my assumption,  the question however just says - "Do whatever you want to do, the work done must be minimum"

@ApoorvaShukla The issue isn't in clarity in your thought process, it is clarity in the question itself. "Work on the mass" is an ambiguous statement. Does it mean work done by all forces? Does it mean work done by an applied force that is not gravity or friction? The second example you give is much better specifying "work done by this force".

@ApoorvaShukla Then it can't be $0$... $W_\text{app}=\Delta K-W_\text{fric}-W_\text{grav}$. To minimize this we want $\Delta K=0$, and since A and E are at the same heigh, $W_\text{grav}=0$, leaving us with $W_\text{app}=-W_\text{fric}\neq0$

@BioPhysicist I agree, if the answer given already in the answer key is zero, the work done being asked has to be the total. Thank you everyone for taking part in the discussion.

Thank you all for their time.

Please do not delete and repost closed questions. Original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824290/174766

If the particle begins and ends at rest, there is no change in kinetic energy which means the net work done by all external forces on the particle (gravity, friction and the applied force) is zero,  per the work energy theorem.
That doesn’t mean no work is done on the particle, only that the net work is zero.
Since the initial and final elevation is the same the net work by gravity is zero. The minimum work needed by the applied force equals the work done by the opposing kinetic friction force, or $\mu mg d_{AE}$
Hope this helps.

I agree to the answer, however the comment by @MarianoG is also very agreeable.

What part of MarinoG comment?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/824483/minimum-work-done-on-a-mass-to-take-it-along-a-path?noredirect=1#comment1856875_824483

@ApoorvaShukla the difficulty with the original question as posed is it isn’t clear minimum work by what. There is the work by gravity which is zero. The work done by the applied force which is positive.  And the work done by friction which is negative.  The minimum work by the applied force is when it equals the work done by friction for net work of zero.

I agree, the question is ambiguous and the fact that the answer to the question is zero implies the work being asked must be the total work. Right. I get it. Thank you.

@ApoorvaShukla RIght. If they wanted the minimum work done by the applied force, that would equal the opposing work of friction (since the net work done by gravity is zero). The opposing work of friction is simply the friction force times the horizontal distance from A to E (since kinetic friction is only due to the component of the weight of the particle normal to the surface.

That would be +$\mu mg AE = 20Joule$. $\mu$ is coefficient of friction. I understood...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ApoorvaShukla Correct. Added to my answer
